# Does introducing a default method to an interface really preserve back-compatibility?

Tags: java-8

I think I'm slightly confused by the introduction of default methods to interfaces in Java. As I understand it, the idea is that default methods can be introduced to existing interfaces without breaking existing code.

If I implement an interface with a non-abstract class, I (of course) have to define implementations of all the abstract methods in the interface. If the interface defines a default method, I inherit the implementation of that method.

If I implement two interfaces, I obviously have to implement the union of the abstract methods defined in both interfaces. I inherit the implementation of all the default methods; however if there happens to be a collision between default methods in the two interfaces, I must override that method in my implementing class.

This sounds fine, but what about the following scenario?

Suppose there's an interface:

```
package com.example ;
/** 
* Version 1.0
*/
public interface A {
  public void foo() ;
  /**
  * The answer to life, the universe, and everything.
  */
  public default int getAnswer() { return 42 ;}
}
```

and a second interface

```
package com.acme ;
/** 
* Version 1.0
*/
public interface B {
  public void bar() ;
}
```

So I can write the following:

```
package com.mycompany ;
public class C implements com.example.A, com.acme.B {
  @Override
  public void foo() {
    System.out.println("foo");
  }
  @Override
  public void bar() {
    System.out.println("bar");
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new C().getAnswer());
  }
}
```

So that should be fine, and indeed

```
java com.mycompany.C
```

displays the result 42.

But now suppose acme.com makes the following change to B:

```
package com.acme ;
/** 
* Version 1.1
*/
public interface B {
  public void bar() ;
  /**
  * The answer to life, the universe, and everything
  * @since 1.1
  */
  public default int getAnswer() {
    return 6*9;
  }
}
```

As I understand it, introducing this method is supposed to be safe. But if I now run the existing com.mycompany.C against the new version, I get a runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Conflicting default methods: com/example/A.getAnswer com/acme/B.getAnswer
at com.mycompany.C.getAnswer(C.java)
at com.mycompany.C.main(C.java:12)
```

That's not entirely surprising, but doesn't it mean that introducing default methods to existing interfaces always runs the risk of breaking existing code? What am I missing?

Comment: Sure it does.  It minimizes the risk as much as possible, but yeah.

Comment: So is the idea that adding default methods to interfaces, at least in the core libraries, is a "one-off": "we're going to make all these library changes in Java 8, but add no further default methods in Java 9"? Because otherwise just upgrading a VM from Java 8 to Java 9 could cause all sorts of existing code to fail: that would be a massive change of philosophy for Java, no?

Answer (score 17):

Although adding a default method with the same name in the two interfaces would make the code fail to compile, but once you resolve the compilation error, the binaries obtained after compiling both the interfaces, and *the class implementing the interfaces*, would be backward compatible.

So, the compatibility is really about binary compatibility. This is being explained in [JLS §13.5.6 - Interface Method Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.5.6):

> Adding a default method, or changing a method from abstract to
>   default, does not break compatibility with pre-existing binaries, but
>   may cause an `IncompatibleClassChangeError` if a pre-existing binary
>   attempts to invoke the method. This error occurs if the qualifying
>   type, T, is a subtype of two interfaces, I and J, where both I and J
>   declare a default method with the same signature and result, and
>   neither I nor J is a subinterface of the other.
>
> In other words, adding a default method is a binary-compatible change
>   because it does not introduce errors at link time, even if it
>   introduces errors at compile time or invocation time. In practice, the
>   risk of accidental clashes occurring by introducing a default method
>   are similar to those associated with adding a new method to a
>   non-final class. In the event of a clash, adding a method to a class
>   is unlikely to trigger a LinkageError, but an accidental override of
>   the method in a child can lead to unpredictable method behavior. Both
>   changes can cause errors at compile time.

The reason you got the `IncompatibleClassChangeError` is probably because, you didn't recompile your `C` class, after adding the default method in `B` interface.

**Also see:**

- [Compatibility Guide for JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html).

Comment: But that would mean that if new default methods are added to interfaces, say in Java 9 core libraries, then potentially any Java application could break when I upgrade? And "the risk of accidental clashes occurring by introducing a default method are similar to those associated with adding a new method to a non-final class" is simply not true, is it? There are no scenarios where adding a method to a class could cause existing binaries which could previously be executed, now fail to execute.

Comment: "The reason you got the IncompatibleClassChangeError is probably because, you didn't recompile your C class, after adding the default method in B interface." Sure... and it wouldn't compile as is. But suppose class C is a class in an application I bought from a vendor, and the change is made in, say, the core libraries...

Comment: @James_D First we're not talking about binaries. Binaries would still be backward compatible, once you get your existing classes to compile. Yes there can be issues that existing code might not compile due to changes in newer Java version, but that you've to cope with.

Comment: @James_D Then you've to get the appropriately modified binaries from the vendor for newer version. The older binaries won't run on the newer version of JRE. I read an article few days back talking about these issues, which I'm unable to find right now :(

Comment: That's my point. That's not backward compatibility. Previously, with a very small number of security-related exceptions, any binary that ran on an older JRE would always run on a newer JRE. That's no longer the case, if more default methods are ever added to core library interfaces.

Comment: @James_D The point is, addition of default method might bring in compilation error to existing code. In which case the binaries that was compiled from those code would not be compatible (of course). If there isn't any compilation error, then the existing binaries would run on JDK 8, or newer version. That is what backward compatibility is all about. You would anyways need to re-compile the now failing source file and get the new binaries.

Comment: @James_D You might want to go through [defender method evolution](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/Defender%20Methods%20v4.pdf) and [state of lambda](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html) by Brian Goetz for deeper understanding. I still haven't gone through them completely though.

Comment: @James_D Added a link to Oracle's Compatibility guide. I guess that will clear most of your doubts.

Comment: So the conclusion from this is that adding default methods to interfaces may break existing code. The Goetz article basically says that (second paragraph of section 6). That would seem to vastly diminish their utility.

Comment: @James_D Yes there is possibility.

Comment: So that's a massive paradigm shift for Java. Unless the intention is that no further default methods will ever be added to core libraries, then there will be situations in the future where there are applications that only run on Java 9 and not on Java 8 (which is nothing new or surprising) *and* applications that only run on Java 8 but not on Java 9 (which is an enormous change in philosophy that I haven't actually seen discussed anywhere). Is that the conclusion?

Comment: @James_D I guess you're expecting that the code that compiles fine on JDK 7 should also compie on JDK 8. Although that is mostly the case, but that is not guaranteed. Because in newer versions, some features moght be removed that was there in earlier version. So basically you would have to modify that part of the code. But if there is no compilation issue, then application running on Java 8 would run on Java 9 without any issue.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about compilation, I'm talking about executing applications. (Assume you don't have access to the source code.) In the past, it has always been guaranteed that if a class compiled and executed on version X, the class file compiled under version X would execute on version Y if Y>=X. (As long as you follow certain basic rules, like not using com.sun classes, etc.) Default methods mean that the application vendor no longer has control over whether their compiled application will be compatible with future JVM releases.

Comment: I work in an academic science environment in which there are dozens and dozens of specialist standalone Java applications. In this environment, this is pretty much a game-changer.

Comment: "But if there is no compilation issue, then application running on Java 8 would run on Java 9 without any issue." The difference is in cases where there *is* a compilation issue. For example, code with a variable name "enum" would compile under 1.4 but would not compile under 1.5 or later. However, *binaries compiled under 1.4 from such code would still run under JVM 1.5 and later*. That is no longer the case: that's a huge difference.

Comment: @James_D Hmm. Yes I guess, that issue will be there. And you've a point there. I'll try searching for some valid and proper explanation from official sources regarding this. But I think that issue is being claimed in those articles I linked. I haven't read it completely, so I might not be able to give a very clear explanation right now :(

Comment: The closest I've found is in the Goetz article on defender methods you linked: "We may choose to relax the runtime semantics to make a program more robust against 
conflicts introduced by inconsistent separate compilation, since this hazard can come 
about quite innocently when a class implements interfaces from two separately 
maintained libraries." Which sounds a bit like "We know this is an issue, and we're working on it." Which is not exactly comforting.

Comment: @James_D - excellent thread. I'm still astonished this isn't talked about more widely and just brushed aside. The probabilities are low but this is a paradigm shift and we can no longer say Java is binary-backwards compatible.

Answer (score 3):

And even if you update your implementation by explicitly choosing which interface to delegate the conflicting default method call to, a subtle change in one of those interfaces can still render your code not compilable.

E.g. you can fix a class `T` like this:

```
interface I {
    default void m() {}
}

interface J {
    default void m() {}
}

class T implements I, J {
    @Override
    public void m() { // forced override
        I.super.m(); // OK
    }
}
```

Everything will be OK, until a change like this:

```
interface J extends I {
    @Override
    default void m() {}
}
```

If only the interface `J` is recompiled, the method `T::m` will still delegate to `I::m`. But compilation of `T` itself will no longer succeed — it will fail with an `error: bad type qualifier I in default super call`:

```
class T implements I, J { // redundant I, but not an error
    @Override
    public void m() { // override not necessary, T::m resolves to J::m
        I.super.m(); // ERROR
    }
}
```