# Are default methods recognized by FXML and/or Scene Builder?

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

Based on my experience the answer to the question in the Title is a resounding 'NO!!!', which I can't believe to be true ... but for my experience. I've created various property type interfaces having 3 methods, for example: getColor(), setColor(Paint c), and ObjectProperty colorProperty(). The get()/set() methods are implemented *in the interface* with the `default` modifier. This generally works fine except in cases involving Scene Builder and FXML. With Scene Builder the above property doesn't show at all *unless* the implementations in the interface are overridden in the class that implements the interface, which defeats the whole purpose of using default methods, ... right? With FXML using the above property, a `PropertyNotFoundException` is thrown for properties implemented only in the interface (without the aforementioned override).

Sample code:

```
public interface TestInterface {
    ObjectProperty<Paint> colorProperty();
    default Paint getColor() {return colorProperty().get();}
    default void setColor(Paint c) {colorProperty().set(c);}
}

public class TestClass implements TestInterface {
    private ObjectProperty<Paint> color;
    public ObjectProperty<Paint> colorProperty() {
        if (color == null)
            color = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "color", Color.GREEN);
        return color;
    }
}
```

Here's an error trace snippet generated from trying to run a test app that includes an FXML file that tries to set a property named 'pressedColor' which is declared and implemented in the same manner as 'color' in sample code above:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException:
...
Caused by: com.sun.javafx.fxml.PropertyNotFoundException: Property "pressedColor" does not exist or is read-only.
```

Here's the offending snippet from the FXML file:

```xml
<RectangleButton pressedColor="#ff6e6e">
```

Would be grateful for any guidance. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some code which shows this happening?

Comment: To reiterate, the default methods work fine outside the context of FXML and/or Scene Builder. For example, if an instance of TestClass would be declared in another class, that other class could access the color value for TestClass simply by invoking the default methods implemented in the interface - this is to be expected. What is unusual is that the expected behavior doesn't appear to work with FXML and/or Scene Builder unless TestClass overrides the default methods, which defeats their purpose, ... right? .. or am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Can you also post some FXML showing what you are expecting to work that is not working?

Comment: Here's a error trace snippet generated from trying to run a test app that includes an FXML file that tries to set a property named 'pressedColor' which is declared and implemented in the same manner as 'color' in sample code above:
    javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
    ... ... ...
    Caused by: com.sun.javafx.fxml.PropertyNotFoundException: Property "pressedColor" does not exist or is read-only.

Here's the offending snippet from the FXML file:
    <RectangleButton pressedColor="#ff6e6e">

Comment: @James_D - Thanks for your input, but regrettably I'm dropping stackoverflow. I've spent more time trying to figure out the editing features here than asking the question - not the first time that's happened - and it's simply not worth the grief and frustration. I'm sure there's a clear description of how to use these features SOMEWHERE, but if so, then - at least for this user - they are very well hidden.

Comment: Hmm. I can recreate that. It's likely the FXML loader code to find property setters was written before default methods. Probably you should file a bug report for this. Aside, but related: I would argue that an abstract class is more appropriate here. You should really only use default methods in interfaces to add functionality to an existing interface. The use you have here is not really the intended use of a default interface.

Comment: Formatting code instructions [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). (To summarize, paste code, select it, press the "code" button `{ }`.)

Comment: @James_D - Thanks for feedback, also for formatting instructions, will give them a try. Agree with suggestion about abstract class - in theory - but in my current project that solution has already proven to be too unwieldy, the interface+default methods is much more flexible and elegant/efficient, especially with JavaFX object properties.

Here's a link to a topic on 'mixins' that discusses the topic:
   https://dzone.com/articles/mixins-pure-java
Apologies in advance if you're already familiar with this. Thanks again!

Comment: Be aware that default methods can cause *binary* back compatibility to fail, though. (To be clear: you write and compile a program. The user runs it. The user updates a library, e.g. the JDK. The program then ceases to run.) This is little documented, but see my [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618493) for a discussion. So it comes down to the level of convenience you need...

Comment: @James_D - Lastly, something that shouldn't be forgotten. I find your tips and suggestions here to be helpful and instructive. Your contributions are much appreciated.

Comment: I would say the issue is related to `FXMLLoader's` parsing and has nothing to do with SceneBuilder, which just uses it. `FXMLLoader` is a part of JavaFX API

Comment: @EugeneRyzhikov, thanks for your reply. You're in a better position than I to know the problem cause, I think you're right, ... but ... the problem makes SceneBuilder look bad b/c custom properties the user expects to see displayed are missing.

Comment: Unfortunately it cannot be fixed in `SceneBuilder` codebase, but the code for OpenJDK is open, if it is urgent for you - submit a fix :)

Comment: I'm keen to take a look into this - is someone able to email me the test code so that I am sure I am testing the right thing? Email jonathan.giles@oracle.com - thanks.

Comment: This seems to be still an issue in 11.0.2. Is there an ticket or any additional communication on this topic? @JonathanGiles

Comment: @mheinzerling I'm not aware of any further information on this. Also, I'm not sure whether J. Giles is still active.

Comment: I tried to post a feature request. I will updated this questions as soon a know more.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a feature request. Maybe there will be an valid answer to this question in the future: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8259916